# Cordova / Ionic - Default App Build Does Not Work Behind a Proxy

Tags: android, ios, cordova, ionic-framework, proxy

I've got a Cordova / Ionic App developed by an external group that we're trying to do some QA testing on. To build out these tests we're attempting to intercept the application with a proxy so we can monitor what API calls the application is making. However, every time we configure the Android or iOS device to use a proxy; the HTTP calls in the application error out.

We have already imported the Certificate Authority of our proxy into the device as a trusted Certificate Authority, and this is confirmed working in the native browser (We can go to SSL sites without any errors/prompts).

The development team is telling us that they haven't done any certificate pinning, or anything "extra" besides what is built into the framework. They are confused as to why our proxying isn't working.

Can anyone tell me what default "platform features" that is preventing our proxying from working, and what we need to tell the development group to give us a build that will allow us to do what we need to do?

Just to be clear, all we have available to us directly is the APK and the IPA file. We do not have the full source-code. We can request the source-code be changed with a new build for us to use; but we cannot just run the Cordova app.

Comment: Do you have a backend something like sails.js? if so your proxy have to accepted by the backend to make the API calls.

Comment: If it was sails.js (and I will ask to see), how would the back-end be validating the request came from the Proxy vs. the device? Typically proxies are relatively transparent.

Comment: You have intercept the API call and redirecting it through your proxy right? So it is not a direct API call ? if it is sails you can define it in config/cors.js :) 

I guess I have understood the question properly. If not please ignore ^_^

Comment: I have configured a proxy for the entire device. That makes all requests go to the proxy first and then sent to the destination (e.g. The same way a corporate proxy might work to give internet access). However, the SSL connection itself is never even setup. Since mobile devices could have a lot of different IP addresses, I do not know what else could be being used to tell the difference between the two.

Comment: Yeah so still you have to define CORS origin in backend. Ask the developer team if they have defined CORS. also can you point out a sample proxy for me?

Comment: We're not getting far enough to get an establised SSL tunnel for the HTTP Request to be sent over. As a result there is never an HTTP Request with an Origin Header value that the backend can reject. :-(.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159916/discussion-between-shashan-sooriyahetti-and-doug).